# Question about groups and opposite elements - A question I got stuck on during test preparation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, permutations

Hello everyone this is my first time on the site, I am preparing for a test I will have in a few more days in the abstract algebra course.

The lecturer gave us a database of questions without solutions, I solved them all, but I could not solve this question. I do not have to submit this question, it's just a question he gave in order to repeat the material.

[the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOnZO.png)

I think the correct answer is e. Because I ruled out all the other options.

a is incorrect, if I choose for example a1 = 1 a2 = 1, both of which are the identity element. And the formula does hold.

b is incorrect, because for a1 = 1, and a2 = -i, the reduction gives 3 and 3 is not equal to the opposite of itself.

c is incorrect, for the same reason b, the formula does not always work.

d is incorrect, for a1 = 1 and a2 = 1, both are opposite of each other. The formula does exist

So e is correct in my opinion, but I'm not sure

Comment: I think you have made a mistake in your calculation for b.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! You are encouraged to write down your problem instead of adding pictures. Here's a mathjax to tutorial to properly type the math: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the comments, why do you think I did not calculate b correctly, can you explain please. I calculated according to the tables, my calculation is correct in my opinion

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "the reduction gives 3 and 3 is not equal to the opposite of itself". As frabala says, the correct answer to the question is c.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my remarks:

Option (a) is indeed false, but your argument is not sufficient to show that.
Option (a) says that the formula holds only when $a_1 = 1$ or $a_2 = 1$. So, to show that (a) is incorrect, you need show that there are some $a_1$ and $a_2$, where none is the identity element, for which the formula holds.

For (b), I don't understand what "does not guarantee correctness of the result" means... Also, why are you looking at the opposite of 3 (or of any element whatsoever)?

Option (c) is what I would choose. Though, we need to show that the reduction is proper. Do you have a formal definition of what a *proper* reduction is? The reason I choose this option as correct is because the reduction respects identities and opposites.

Option (d) is indeed incorrect and your argument proves it.

Option (e) is incorrect, because option (c) is correct.

Comment: It seems  clear what the reduction is. You can use the isomorphism between the two groups and the fact that we can carry out multiplication in $G_2$ to enable fast multiplication in $G_1$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, in b I calculated the inverse element, to show that the formula does not hold. In the formula itself the opposite element should be calculated, in my opinion at least that is how it should be done

Comment: @anihaham $f^{-1}(3)$ does not mean "the opposite of 3". It means "the inverse of 3 according to the reduction $f$". So, $f^{-1}(3) = -i$, and that is because $f(-i)=3$.

Comment: Aww, my mistake in understanding, I realized, now it's clear to me, thanks so much for the help